# Android popup which resize automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, circular-dependency

today I'm facing an issue with the layouts in android.

This is my goal :
I wan't a popup with a Title, a body containing a scrollView (in case of Big data) and a button.

This is what my layout look like in the big lines:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/body_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"//To permit the scrollview to resize depending of the data amount
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My very long sentence which may take all the screen size and maybe more"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/body_scrollview">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the text is short, then no issue, the button is still visible, but if the text is very big (I mean bigger than the screen can support) the button disappears.

I could do a bottom alignment with the button and then put the above property inside the scrollView but it will cause the popup to always take all of the height size (even if the text is very small) which is not what I want.

Any idea of how I should do it ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: put the button at the bottom of the scrollview or use an `AlertDialog` and use the buttons there

Comment: Ok I will do it. I keep you in touch.